# A bunch of tag rename/synonym requests

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

([See related chat discussion here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/457472#457472))

**NOTE:** Most are small, so doesn't need special moderator attention, just update my post when you help.

**Proposed tag renames/synonyms:** (*old tag --> new tag*)

- [.net](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net) --> [.net-framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework) (and all version variants) **Done**
- [hd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hd) --> [720p](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/720p) - Changed to [high-definition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/high-definition) **Done**
- [fullhd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fullhd) --> [1080p](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/1080p) **Done**
- [3d](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/3d) --> more specific 3d tags: [3d-ready](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/3d-ready) [3d-vision](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/3d-vision) [3d-multimedia](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/3d-multimedia) [3d-modeling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/3d-modeling) **Done**
- [7zip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/7zip) --> [7-zip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/7-zip) **Done**
- [aboutconfig](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aboutconfig) --> [about-config](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/about-config) **Done**
- [adaptor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adaptor) --> [adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adapter) **Done**
- [addressbook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/addressbook) --> [address-book](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/address-book) **Done**
- [adhoc-network](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adhoc-network) --> [ad-hoc-network](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ad-hoc-network) (to match [ad-hoc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ad-hoc)) **Done**
- [admin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/admin) --> [administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/administrator) **Done**
- [album-art](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/album-art) --> [album-artwork](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/album-artwork) **Done** - but reversed.
- [aliases](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aliases) --> [alias](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alias) **Done**
- [amplifier](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amplifier) --> [amplification](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/amplification) **Done**
- [analytics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/analytics) + [analyzer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/analyzer) --> [analysis](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/analysis) **Done**
- [appstore](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/appstore) --> [app-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/app-store) **Done**
- [apt](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apt) + [apt-get](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apt-get) --> [aptitude](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aptitude) **Done**
- [archive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/archive) + [archivers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/archivers) --> [archiving](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/archiving) **Done**
- [automatic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/automatic) --> [automation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/automation) **Done**
- [autostart-application](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autostart-application) --> [startup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/startup) **Done**
- [avg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/avg) --> [avg-antivirus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/avg-antivirus) **Done**
- [backups](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/backups) --> [backup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/backup) **Done**
- [bandwith](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bandwith) --> [bandwidth](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bandwidth) **Done**
- [benchmark](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/benchmark) --> [benchmarking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/benchmarking) **Done**
- [block](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/block) --> [blocking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blocking) **Done**
- [blog](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blog) --> [blogging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogging) **Done**
- [book](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/book) --> [books](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/books) **Done**
- [bookmark](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bookmark) --> [bookmarks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bookmarks) **Done**
- [bootcamp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bootcamp) --> [boot-camp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/boot-camp) **Done**
- [caching](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/caching) --> [cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cache) **Done**
- [cdrom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cdrom) --> [cd-rom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd-rom) **Done**
- [cell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cell) --> [cells](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cells) **Done**
- [centos5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/centos5) --> [centos-5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/centos-5) **Done**
- [changes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/changes) --> [change](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/change) **Done**
- [character](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/character) --> [characters](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/characters) **Done**
- [charge](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charge) --> [charging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charging) **Done**
- [chart](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chart) --> [charts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/charts) **Done**
- [coding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/coding) + [programmers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/programmers) --> [programming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/programming)  **Done**
- [commands](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/commands) --> [command](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command) **Done**
- [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comment) --> [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comments) **Done**
- [compare](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compare) --> [comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison) **Done**
- [compose](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compose) --> [compositing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compositing) was changed to [composition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/composition) **Done**
- [config](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/config) --> [configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/configuration) **Done**
- [connections](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connections) --> [connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection) **Done**
- [contact](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/contact) --> [contacts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/contacts) **Done**
- [content](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/content) --> [contents](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/contents) **Done**
- [convert](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/convert) + [converter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/converter) + [converting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/converting) --> [conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conversion) **Done**
- [copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copying) --> [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) **Done**
- [customize](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/customize) --> [customization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/customization) **Done**
- [dashboards](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dashboards) --> [dashboard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dashboard)
- [data-rescue](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-rescue) --> [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)
- [ddwrt](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ddwrt) --> [dd-wrt](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dd-wrt) **Done**
- [debugging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debugging) --> [debug](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debug) **Done**
- [deletion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/deletion) --> [delete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/delete) **Done**
- [device](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/device) --> [devices](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/devices) **Done**
- [dialogbox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dialogbox) --> [dialog](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dialog) **Done**
- [diskimage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diskimage) --> [disk-image](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-image) **Done**
- [diskspace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diskspace) --> [disk-space](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-space) **Done**
- [dlink](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dlink) + [dlink-dns323](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dlink-dns323) --> [d-link](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/d-link) **Done**
- [dmg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dmg) --> [dmg-image](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dmg-image) **Done**
- [document](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/document) --> [documents](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/documents) **Done**
- [domains](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/domains) --> [domain](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/domain) **Done**
- [downloads](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/downloads) --> [download](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/download) **Done**
- [draw](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/draw) --> [drawing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drawing) **Done**
- [drive-letters](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive-letters) --> [drive-letter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive-letter) **Done**
- [dual-monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitors) --> [dual-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor) **Done**
- [ecommerce](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce) --> [e-commerce](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) **Done**
- [edit](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/edit) --> [editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/editing) **Done**
- [e-mail](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/e-mail) --> [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email) **Done**
- [equation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/equation) --> [equations](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/equations) **Done**
- [ergonomic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ergonomic) --> [ergonomics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ergonomics) **Done**
- [event](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/event) --> [events](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/events) **Done**
- [executables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/executables) --> [executable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/executable) **Done**
- [failed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failed) --> [failure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure) **Done**
- [fans](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fans) --> [fan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fan) **Done**
- [feeds](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/feeds) --> [feed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/feed) **Done**
- [file-copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copy) --> [file-copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copying)  **Done**
- [filesystem](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filesystem) --> [file-systems](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-systems) **Done**
- [firefox3.6](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox3.6) --> [firefox-3.6](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox-3.6)
- [floppy-disk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk) --> [floppy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/floppy)  **Done**
- [folders](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/folders) --> [folder](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/folder) **Done**
- [font](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/font) --> [fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fonts) **Done**
- [formating](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/formating) --> [formatting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/formatting) **Done**
- [forums](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/forums) --> [forum](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/forum) **Done**
- [frameworks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/frameworks) --> [framework](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/framework) **Done**
- [frontrow-remote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/frontrow-remote) --> [front-row-remote](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/front-row-remote) (to match [front-row](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/front-row)) **Done**
- [ftp-client](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ftp-client) --> [ftp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ftp) **Done**
- [functions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/functions) --> [function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/function) **Done**
- [gadget](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gadget) --> [gadgets](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gadgets) **Done**
- [games](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/games) --> [gaming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gaming) **Done**
- [googleapis](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/googleapis) --> [google-apis](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-apis) **Done**
- [google-sketch-up](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-sketch-up) --> [google-sketchup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-sketchup) **Done**
- [group](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/group) + [grouping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/grouping) --> [groups](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/groups) **Done**
- [growlnotify](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/growlnotify) --> [growl-notify](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/growl-notify) **Done**
- [h264](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/h264) --> [h.264](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/h.264) **Done**
- [hacking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hacking) --> [hack](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hack) **Done**
- [hard-disk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-disk) --> [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) **Done**
- [hash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hash) --> [hashing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hashing) **Done**
- [header](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/header) --> [headers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/headers) **Done**
- [highlight](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/highlight) --> [highlighting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/highlighting) **Done**
- [home-dir](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-dir) --> [home-directory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-directory) **Done**
- [home-network](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-network) --> [home-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-networking) **Done**
- [home-page](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-page) --> [homepage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/homepage) **Done**
- [hosted](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hosted) --> [hosting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hosting) **Done**
- [hosts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hosts) --> [host](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/host) + [hosting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hosting) + [hosts-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hosts-file) **To Be Done**
- [hotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hotkey) --> [hotkeys](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hotkeys) **Done**
- [error-404](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error-404) --> [http-status-code-404](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404) **Done**
- [hyperlinks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hyperlinks) --> [hyperlink](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hyperlink) **Done**
- [icon](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/icon) --> [icons](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/icons)  **Done**
- [iis7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iis7) --> [iis-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iis-7) **Done**
- [image](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image) --> [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images) **Done**
- [indexing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/indexing) --> [index](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/index) **Done**
- [installing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/installing) --> [installation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/installation)
- [internet-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-access) --> [internet-connection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-connection)
- [jumpers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/jumpers) --> [jumper](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/jumper) **Done**
- [kde4](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kde4) --> [kde-4](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kde-4) **Done**
- [key-mapping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/key-mapping) --> [keymap](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keymap) **Done**
- [key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/key) --> [keys](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keys) **Done**
- [lags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lags) --> [lag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lag) **Done**
- [library](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/library) --> [libraries](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/libraries) **Done**
- [line](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/line) --> [lines](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lines) **Done**
- [link](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/link) + [linking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linking) + [linker](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linker) --> [links](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/links) **Done**
- [livemeeting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/livemeeting) --> [live-meeting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/live-meeting) **Done**
- [locking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/locking) --> [lock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lock) **Done**
- [log](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/log) + [logs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logs) --> [logging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logging) **Done**
- [logon](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logon) --> [login](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/login) **Done**
- [logoff](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logoff) --> [logout](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logout) **Done**
- [macbookpro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro) --> [macbook-pro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macbook-pro) **Done**
- [macmini](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macmini) --> [mac-mini](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-mini) **Done**
- [mail](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mail) --> [email](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email) **Done**
- [map](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/map) + [maps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/maps) --> [mapping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mapping) **Done**
- [media-centre](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/media-centre) --> [media-center](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/media-center) **Done**
- [meeting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/meeting) --> [meetings](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/meetings) **Done**
- [menu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/menu) --> [menus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/menus) **Done**
- [meta](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/meta) --> [metadata](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/metadata) **Done**
- [middle-click](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/middle-click) --> [middle-mouse-button](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/middle-mouse-button) **Done**
- [migrate](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/migrate) --> [migration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/migration) **Done**
- [mime](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mime) --> [mime-types](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mime-types) **Done**
- [mirror](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mirror) --> [mirroring](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mirroring) **Done**
- [movie](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/movie) --> [movies](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/movies) **Done**
- [msn](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msn) + [msn-messenger](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msn-messenger) --> [windows-live-messenger](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-live-messenger) **Done**
- [multicore](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multicore) --> [multi-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-core) **Done**
- [multitouch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multitouch) --> [multi-touch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-touch) **Done**
- [musicians](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/musicians) --> [music](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/music) **Done**
- [network-share](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-share) --> [network-shares](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-shares) **Done**
- [newline](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/newline) --> [newlines](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/newlines) **Done**
- [newsletter](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/newsletter) --> [newsletters](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/newsletters) **Done**
- [openoffice](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/openoffice) --> [openoffice.org](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/openoffice.org) **Done**
- [organize](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/organize) + [organizer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/organizer) --> [organizing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/organizing) **Done**
- [overheating](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/overheating) --> [overheat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/overheat) **Done**
- [package](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/package) + [packaging](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/packaging) --> [packages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/packages) **Done**
- [page](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/page) --> [pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pages) **Done**
- [panels](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/panels) --> [panel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/panel) **Done**
- [paragraph](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/paragraph) --> [paragraphs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/paragraphs) **Done**
- [password](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password) --> [passwords](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/passwords) **Done**
- [pinned](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pinned) --> [pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pinning) **Done**
- [pivottable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pivottable) --> [pivot-table](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pivot-table) **Done**
- [playlist](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/playlist) --> [playlists](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/playlists) **Done**
- [plugin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plugin) --> [plugins](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/plugins) **Done**
- [podcast](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/podcast) --> [podcasts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/podcasts) **Done**
- [popup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/popup) --> [popups](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/popups) **Done**
- [portforwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/portforwarding) --> [port-forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/port-forwarding) **Done**
- [power-line-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/power-line-networking) --> [power-line-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/power-line-networking) **Done**
- [presentation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/presentation) --> [presentations](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/presentations) **Done**
- [print](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/print) --> [printing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printing) **Done**
- [profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/profiles) --> [profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/profile) **Done**
- [raid1](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raid1) --> [raid-1](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raid-1) **Done**
- [raid10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raid10) --> [raid-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raid-10) **Done**
- [raid5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raid5) --> [raid-5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raid-5) **Done**
- [recover](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recover) --> [recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recovery) **Done**
- [redirect](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/redirect) --> [redirection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/redirection) **Done**
- [remap](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remap) --> [remapping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remapping) **Done**
- [remove](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remove) --> [removal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/removal) **Done**
- [repeat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repeat) --> [repeating](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repeating) **Done**
- [replace](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/replace) --> [replacement](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/replacement) **Done**
- [resource](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resource) --> [resources](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resources) **Done**
- [restrict](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/restrict) --> [restrictions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/restrictions) **Done**
- [rhel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rhel) --> [rhel-5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rhel-5) **Done**
- [rosetta](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rosetta) --> [rosetta-stone](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rosetta-stone) **Done**
- [routers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/routers) --> [router](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/router) **Done**
- [rule](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rule) --> [rules](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rules) **Done**
- [running](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/running) --> [run](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/run) **Done**
- [safemode](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/safemode) --> [safe-mode](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/safe-mode) **Done**
- [scheduled-task](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-task) --> [scheduled-tasks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks) **Done**
- [screensharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screensharing) --> [screen-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen-sharing) **Done**
- [scroll](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scroll) --> [scrolling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scrolling) **Done**
- [sector](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sector) --> [sectors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sectors) **Done**
- [secure-delete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/secure-delete) --> [secure-erase](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/secure-erase) **Done**
- [seed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/seed) --> [seeding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/seeding) **Done**
- [select](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/select) --> [selection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/selection) **Done**
- [servers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/servers) --> [server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/server) **Done**
- [service](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/service) --> [services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/services) **Done**
- [sharedaccess](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharedaccess) --> [shared-access](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shared-access) **Done**
- [shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) --> [shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts) **Done**
- [socket](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/socket) --> [sockets](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sockets) **Done**
- [sort](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sort) --> [sorting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sorting) **Done**
- [sounds](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sounds) --> [sound](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound) **Done**
- [special-character](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/special-character) --> [special-characters](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/special-characters) **Done**
- [style](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/style) --> [styles](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/styles)  **Done**
- [subversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/subversion) --> [svn](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/svn) **Done**
- [synaptic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptic) --> [synaptics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptics) **Done**
- [table](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/table) --> [tables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tables) **Done**
- [tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tag) --> [tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tags) **Done**
- [taskmanager](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/taskmanager) --> [task-manager](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/task-manager) **Done**
- [task](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/task) --> [tasks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tasks) **Done**
- [temp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/temp) --> [temperature](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/temperature) **Done**
- [template](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/template) --> [templates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/templates) **Done**
- [terminalservices](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/terminalservices) --> [terminal-services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services) **Done**
- [text-editor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/text-editor) --> [text-editors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/text-editors) **Done**
- [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/thread) --> [threads](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/threads)  **Done**
- [titlebar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/titlebar) --> [title-bar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/title-bar) **Done**
- [tool](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tool) --> [tools](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tools) **Done**
- [turn-off](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/turn-off) --> [shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shutdown) **Done**
- [undelete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/undelete) --> [recover](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recover) **Done**
- [unlock](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unlock) --> [unlocking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unlocking) **Done**
- [update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/update) --> [updates](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/updates) **Done**
- [utility](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utility) --> [utilities](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utilities) **Done**
- [variable](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/variable) --> [variables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/variables) **Done**
- [versions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/versions) --> [version](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/version) **Done**
- [videochat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/videochat) --> [video-chat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-chat) **Done**
- [videos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/videos) --> [video](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video) **Done**
- [virtual-box](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-box) --> [virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) **Done**
- [virtualhosts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualhosts) --> [virtual-host](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-host) **Done**
- [virtual-machines](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machines) --> [virtual-machine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) **Done**
- [vlc-media-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vlc-media-player) --> [vlc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vlc) **Done**
- [warnings](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/warnings) --> [warning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/warning) **Done**
- [webhosting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webhosting) --> [web-hosting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting) **Done**
- [widget](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/widget) --> [widgets](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/widgets) **Done**
- [window-managers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/window-managers) --> [window-manager](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/window-manager) **Done**
- [windows7-professional](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows7-professional) --> [windows-7-professional](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7-professional) **Done**
- [xserver](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xserver) --> [x-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/x-server) **Done**

**Other thing I've noted:**

- File types might benefit from being merged to [file-types](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-types), as the file type is listed in question/title.
  **To Be Dicussed**
- On a next iteration in the far future I'll check tags like [multiple](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple), death to the meta/part tags!
  **To Be Done**

Some Added by Kronos:

- [external-harddrive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-harddrive) + [external-hdd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hdd) --> [external-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-hard-drive) **Done**

Comment: Holy crap!... I'm glad I'm not a mod at the moment ;)

Comment: The synaptic -> synaptics is unfortunate. There is an IT company called Synaptics, but there is also the Synaptic package manager for Linux. As of now, most questions with the synaptics tag are about the package manager, so mistagged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This project, or this particular phase is [status-completed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/status-completed).  **Kudos to [TomWiji](https://superuser.com/users/9666/tomwij)** for his excellent work in creating this list!

Comment: You guys are nuts

Comment: thanks for your support @KronoS. ;) that's why I'm a moderator and you're my slave.

Comment: o_0 woah @studiohack