# More for burnination and synonyms

Tags: support, retag-request

Burnination:

- [first](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/first)
- [function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/function)
- [general](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/general)
- [hardware-selection](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-selection) (the two questions with this tag are closed, and hardware combination seems better anyway; might be better to make them synonyms though)
- [home](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home) (it does have a lot of uses, but never adds anything to the question)
- <strike>[idea](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/idea)</strike>
- [improvements](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/improvements)
- [inception](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/inception)
- [interactive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interactive) (I can see an argument for keeping it though, just seems weak to me)
- [interaction](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interaction) (burn both, or make them synonyms of each other)
- <strike>[junk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/junk)</strike> (synonym created with [spam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spam))
- [key](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/key) (no questions tagged)
- [kids](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kids)
- [low](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/low)
- [malicious](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/malicious)
- [meaning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/meaning)
- [most-visited](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/most-visited)
- [multiple](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple)
- [new](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/new)
- <strike>[not-programming-related](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/not-programming-related)</strike>
- [novice](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/novice)
- [number](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/number)
- [old](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old)
- [optical](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/optical) (there are better fitting tags all the time)
- [outdoor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outdoor)
- [rugged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rugged)
- [people](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/people)
- <strike>[picassa](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/picassa)</strike> (rare typing mistake)
- [pranks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pranks)
- [reliance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reliance)
- [room](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/room)
- [add](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/add)
- [view](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/view)

**EDIT:** [future](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/future) (don't know how I missed that one...)

Synonyms:

- <s>[flashplayer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flashplayer) -> [flash-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-player)</s>
- <s>[graphic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphic)->[graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics)</s>
- <s>[help](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/help) ->[help-files](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/help-files)</s>
- <s>[hex](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hex) -> [hexadecimal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hexadecimal)</s>
- <s>[icalcs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/icalcs)->[icacls](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/icacls)</s>
- <s>[incremental](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/incremental)->[incremental-backup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/incremental-backup)</s> (as it's used now anyway, with one exception)
- <s>[interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interface)->[interfaces](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interfaces)</s>
- <s>[iso](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iso) ->[iso-image](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/iso-image)</s>
- <s>[language](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/language) ->[languages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/languages)</s>
- <s>[limitations](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/limitations) ->[limits](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/limits)</s>
- [list](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/list)->[lists](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lists)
- [logoff](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logoff)->[logout](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/logout)
- [man](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/man)->[man-pages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/man-pages)
- [mediakeys](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mediakeys)->[media-keys](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/media-keys)
- <s>[networkdrive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networkdrive)->[network-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-drive)</s>
- [parallelism](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/parallelism)->[parallel-processing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/parallel-processing)
- [persistance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/persistance)->[persistence](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/persistence)
- [porting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/porting) -> [port](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/port)
- [processes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/processes) -> [process](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process)
- <s>[raid0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raid0)->[raid-0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raid-0)</s>
- [recurrence](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recurrence) ->[recursion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recursion)
- [recursive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recursive) ->[recursion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recursion)
- [resizing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resizing) ->[resize](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resize)

Comment: Crossed-out = completed. We'll need to wait for a Dev to do burnination, since mods can't do that ourselves.

Comment: Great list! I think we've burninated `keys` once already, don't know why that popped up again.

Comment: @slhck, by tomorrow I will probably have gone through all the tags. Unfortunately, I don't know enough to do more.

Comment: @soandos: [Duplicate](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2043/9666)! Just kidding, nice job on looking into them again... +1 :)

Comment: @Tom thanks, the irony would have killed me ;)

Comment: I've added two more candidates: [add](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/add) and [view](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/view)

Answer (score 2):

Watch out with [function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/function), there are some questions that can be combined into [worksheet-function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function).

---

Watch out with [multiple](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple), there are a lot of questions here that can get combined with another tag.

eg. [multiple-monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors), [multiple-instances](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-instances), [multiple-users](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-users), ...

Comment: The point is that the tag should not exist. Agreed that should be replaced in some cases first.