# Unsynonomize [synaptic] and [synaptics]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

**Synaptics** is a company that makes human interface devices like touchpads.  **Synaptic** is a Linux package manager that works with Apt.  At some point in the past, these two tags were incorrectly synonomized.

[synaptics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptics) is a manufacturer tag and should be added to the list for tag cleanup after any questions about the package manager have been separated and retagged.

If the two tags were merged as well as synonomized, the cleanup will be more complicated.  There are 158 questions with the synonomized tag.  It looks like about 35 of those relate to package management.  A search for questions with both "synaptic" and "package" text found 99, while "synaptic" incorrectly paired with "touchpad" found 233.  So if necessary, questions could be retagged with a new [synaptics-touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptics-touchpad) tag, or the existing generic [touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/touchpad), after which retagging the package management questions with [synaptic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptic) or [synaptic-pkg-mgr](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptic-pkg-mgr) wouldn't be a massive task.  If the more unique [synaptic-pkg-mgr](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptic-pkg-mgr) tag is created, it will be easy to retag the package management questions first, then cleanup the touchpad questions.

Comment: Note: all of this has been completed.  New [synaptics-touchpad] and [synaptic-pkg-mgr] tags to avoid ambiguity, tag wiki excerpts, [synaptics] tag cleaned out and reflected on the Manufacturer tags Meta post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that they are distinct and separate.

It seems that the original synonym was created [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2043/a-bunch-of-tag-rename-synonym-requests) and someone even mentioned the unfortunate nature of the synonym.

I have broken the synonym, a tag wiki should probably be created for [synaptic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptic).

The [synaptics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptics) still needs to be cleaned up as you mentioned.

Comment: [synaptic-pkg-mgr] would be less likely to be misused in the future.  I'll look at going with that.